# Unity not updating

Tags: unity-game-engine, updates

I'm currently working with other classmates in a Unity project. My Unity version is 5.5.0f3 but it seems they are running 5.5.1f1 which is more recent.

When they open my changes they get the following message "oh no the project was saved with 5.5.0f3 and you're using a newer version"

I've tried updating but it shows that I'm at the most recent version of Unity. How do I force the updates?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the Unity website and download the latest version.

Comment: I figured that was a solution, but I want to avoid downloading every time the updates aren't detected